# Do i create models from entity framework models or edit the entity framework models and use them in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have been looking for a while for a straight answer but can't seem to find one.

I am trying to learn the MVVM pattern in WPF and have been wondering if my models are what the entity framework creates or if I should create models which are basically a copy of entity framework models.

For example my entity framework model for my very basic tblMyEmployees is as follows

```
    public partial class tblMyEmployee
{
    public int pkEmployee { get; set; }
    public string strFirstName { get; set; }
    public string strLastName { get; set; }
}
```

So should i create a model basically copying and pasting the properties from the entity framework generated model and implement INotifyPropertyChanged using my BaseViewModel, and also any other properties I could find useful, like this

```
class EmployeeModel: BaseViewModel
{
    public int pkEmployee { get; set; }
    private string _strFirstName;
    public string strFirstName
    {
        get { return _strFirstName; }
        set
        {
            _strFirstName = value;
            SetProperty(ref _strFirstName, value);
        }
    }
    private string _strLastName;
    public string strLastName
    {
        get { return _strLastName; }
        set
        {
            _strLastName = value;
            SetProperty(ref _strLastName, value);
        }
    }
    private string _strFullName;
    public string strFullName
    {
        get { return strFirstName + " " + strLastName; }
    }
}
```

Or should I add my additional properties and implement INotifyPropertyChanged to the generated model instead?

This may seem like a really stupid question but it's one i would like a clear answer for as for a long while i haven't been able to find an answer to.

The comment at the top of the generated model makes me wonder if i should create my own models based on it

//     This code was generated from a template.

//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.

//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question that's been asked countless times here, although it might be tricky finding an answer that suits you because there are multiple ways of solving it. Options include:

1. For each of your model classes create a corresponding view model.
2. Use [PropertyChange.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/propertychanged.fody/) to add INPC for you at compile time.
3. Use something like [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2008/08/04/implement-inotifypropertychanged-with-castledynamicproxy/) to inject INPC at runtime (there are some important issues to consider with this though, your ORM needs to provide the ability to let you proxy both the model objects it creates and especially any collections).
4. Do INPC manually. Chances are that changes to your models always come from the view, in which case INPC isn't actually required. In this case the only changes that need to propagate back the other way are collection additions and removals, in which case you leave them as regular lists (say) and invoke the INPC change event manually whenever you change the list. (This is a bit of an ugly solution, and there can be performance issues, but it's a possibility).

Which one I use myself depends on the project. I used to use #3, but it's so tightly coupled to the ORM that it's not my preferred option anymore. For Xamarin work I tend to use #2, but for most WPF stuff I tend to use view models to manage collections but bind directly to model properties where possible. The ability to have multiple parts of your view binding to the same view model seems appealing at first, until you realize that it creates for a more confusing interface and interferes with with any kind of undo/cancel functionality that your users might be expecting.

UPDATE: if you do go down the route of declaring all your view model properties explicitly then you'll find yourself writing the same code over and over. I save a lot of time by putting this functionality into a code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>propc</Title>
            <Shortcut>propc</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for an automatically implemented change notification property</Description>
            <Author>Mark Feldman</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>type</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property type</ToolTip>
                    <Default>int</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>property</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>MyProperty</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[private $type$ _$property$;
    public $type$ $property$
    {
        get { return this._$property$;}
        set
        {
            if (this._$property$ != value)
            {
                this._$property$ = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.$property$);
            }
        }
    }
    $end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Import that via Tools->Code Snippets Manager and then type 'propc' anywhere in a class followed by 2 tabs, that will generate most of the boilerplate code for a INPC property with a backend field and let you replace the type and name:

```
private string _MyText;
public string MyText
{
    get { return this._MyText; }
    set
    {
        if (this._MyText != value)
        {
            this._MyText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.MyText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the issue maybe my in ability to get my head around things at the moment. So should I just use the generated models without INPC on it? and in my ViewModel have an ObservableCollection<tblEmployee> where i can track changes like added, modified and deleted? and add my strFullName property in the ViewModel as well?

Comment: Yep, if you're just starting out then that's definitely a good way to go. It's a bit more work, but you'll get a much better grasp of how data-binding is working and you'll be able to set breakpoints on all your view-model properties to make sure your bindings are working properly etc. I'll updated my answer and include a code snippet that will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out, I really appreciate it. The snippet will be definitely very useful to me! I know i'll get to grips with MVVM in time, just starting out it can be rather confusing to know if i'm on the right track!

Comment: Also just one more thing i wanted to ask if you don't mind. Do i put my code for filling the observable collection in my ViewModel also? or create a seperate class to hande all my data retrival code? I mean the Using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities()) code

Comment: Again, it really depends on your application and your database solution. The easiest solution is to replace any lists with an ObservableCollection immediately after you load your entities from the db. The problem with this is that when you save your entity back out again the db will usually see that the list object itself has changed and it will serialize every single item in the list back to the db again. Not a big deal if you don't have many records, but performance will very quickly spiral out of control.

Comment: So another solution is to create a view model that contains a reference to the model and also shadows of any lists, which are of type ObservableCollection. Now when you create a new list object you add it to both the model list (so that the db will get updated) and the view model ObservableCollection (so that the view will get updated). The latter object might be the model entity itself or it might be a matching view model with all the properties exposed with INPC. This obviously makes your code a bit more complex, because the two lists have to stay synchronized, but it's easy to implement.

Comment: If you're working on a project with a particularly large model layer, or if multiple people are constantly updating it, you may then opt to put INPC in the models themselves. That's where my other solutions come into play. Some MVVM purists say not to do this because they think it breaks the paradigm, I personally disagree, but it's a decision you'll have to make for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Mark Feldman in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856785/249665, there are several ways to do it.

In most cases the viewmodels and the domain entities (models) are different; they would only be identical in a really simple CRUD application.

For instance, the viewmodel may contain a subset of the properties in a model, or properties from several models.

In addition to this, the viewmodel has properties that not exist in the model. For instance, maybe only some users are allowed to view or edit particular properties; the viewmodel would then have properties that indicate that these fields are hidden or readonly.

Also, the viewmodel probably have things like lists for combo boxes etc, and the values for these might come from other models (value objects).

Here is my current approach (using NHibernate, I have unfortunately very little experience of EF, but I guess that there is no difference on this level).

1. Domain entities should not implement INPC
2. Avoid to much logic inside viewmodels
3. Factor out code for loading viewmodels to separate classes.
4. Factor out code for performing updates to separate classes.
5. Validate the data for 3 and 4 using FluentValidation.

For 3 and 4 above, have a look at https://jimmybogard.com/vertical-slice-architecture/

You could end up with classes like these:
* Employee model
* Create new Employee ViewModel
* Edit Salary ViewModel
* GetNewEmployee Query (this one would get all the data needed for creating a new employee, such as list of departments, positions etc.)
* SaveNewEmployee Command (persists the new employee)
* GetEmployee Salary Query (this one maybe checks if the user is allowed to view but not change the salary, perhaps it gets min and max salary, salary types etc.)
* UpdateSalary Command
* Validate new Employee
* Validate Salary

Probably you will discover that all these classes have some common logic. There are several ways to handle this. Often that logic can be moved to methods in the models; in other cases you need to add separate service classes that implement such common logic.

Comment: Thank you for this, it really helps and i appreciate you taking the time to help. It is making sense, I just need to get the time to get back to working on my WPF application and put this into practice. Where I work is all Winforms so I am trying to learn WPF MVVM outside of work to get a head start as I think WPF MVVM is a good step to make from Winforms. It's how I would like to write future applications for work. Most likely wil be able to get back on it this over the coming the weekend.